# MailEnable management console can not be opend and shows the error

Tags: plesk, mail-server

When i try to open MailEnable management console it try to open diagnostic tool,i am using 5.5 version of Standard Edition on windows 2008.
here is the error :
"do you wish to refresh diagnostic report ? if you have a large amount of post office this may take some time"
what should i do to fix this problem and open Mail Enable management.

Answer (score 0):

How about to ask on MailEnable forum http://forum.mailenable.com/ or upgrade to latest MailEnable version supported by Plesk? (Plesk is not upgrading MailEnable at Plesk upgrade)

Usually upgrade of MailEnable passing without any issues.